# Кеширование PHP и повторная загрузка по требованию

Tags: php

Есть PHP скрипт, который получает данные через апи, но загрузка страницы длится 10-15 секунд, что очень долго

Нужно либо кешировать его, и обновлять по требованию (модуль - инвентарь пользователя), либо же, что лучше, сделать его загрузку ПОСЛЕ загрузки файла шаблона (видел подобную реализацию подобных модулей не раз)

Такой долгой загрузка после добавления нескольких функций, а именно:

```
$price = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=5&appid=730&market_hash_name=".$market_name_formatted;       //получаем данные о предмете    
$string = file_get_contents($price);    // вытягиваем данные о предмете   
$obj = json_decode($string);            // преобразуем данные   
$lowest_price = $obj->{'median_price'}; // получем среднюю цену предмета
```

Может что-то не так в коде? Можно ускорить загрузку нужных мне данных?

Answer (score 1):

Как понял, вы можете загрузить основную страницу без этих данных. а долгий запрос подтянуть ajax'ом. Как правила пользователи терпимо относятся к подобным подгрузкам.

Comment: А как это реализовать, не подскажете?